# Replace words in list that later will be used in variable

Tags: python

I have a file which currently stores a string `eeb39d3e-dd4f-11e8-acf7-a6389e8e7978`
which I am trying to pass into as a variable to my subprocess command.

My current code looks like this

```
with open(logfilnavn, 'r') as t:
                test = t.readlines()
                print(test)
```

But this prints `['eeb39d3e-dd4f-11e8-acf7-a6389e8e7978\n']` and I don't want the part with **['\n']** to be passed into my command, so i'm trying to remove them by using replace.

```
 with open(logfilnavn, 'r') as t:
            test = t.readlines()
            removestrings = test.replace('[', '').replace('[', '').replace('\\', '').replace("'", '').replace('n', '')
            print(removestrings)
```

I get an exception value saying this so how can I replace these with nothing and store them as a string for my subprocess command?

> 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

so how can I replace these with nothing and store them as a string for my subprocess command?

Comment: `readlines` will return a list of lines, its not actually a string. You can't use `replace` with a list.

Comment: @SufiyanGhori Using this code `test = t.readlines().rstrip()` i'm getting exception value **'list' object has no attribute 'rstrip'**

Comment: Yeah that's what i've also begun realizing @MuhammadAhmad, but I really don't know what else to do. I've been trying for 3+ hours now.

Comment: @SufiyanGhori Yeah that prints it without these values, but I still can't pass it into my command as a variable since it's a NoneType

Comment: @LesnieSncheider The question is: will there only be one line in the file, or there can be more? If there'll only be one line, you don't really need `readlines` then.

Comment: @SufiyanGhori It never is irrelevant of what OP is trying to do. I really don't think that OP is just trying to print each line. The question is: what does he really want to do with it. And if there'll not be more than 1 line in the file, he doesn't need any loop or `readlines` etc.

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad, this is why i added both scenarios in my answer.

Comment: To be clear there is **only** this line in the file, nothing else. @SufiyanGhori

Comment: @LesnieSncheider, I have added the answer on how to use `readline` to read thsi one line :) please read my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error because `readlines` returns a list object. Since you mentioned in the comment that there is just one line in the file, its better to use `readline()` instead,

```
line = "" # so you can use it as a variable outside `with` scope,
with open("logfilnavn", 'r') as t:
    line = t.readline()
    print(line)

# output,
eeb39d3e-dd4f-11e8-acf7-a6389e8e7978
```

Comment: thats ok @LesnieSncheider

Answer (score 1):

readline() returns a list. Try print(test[0].strip())

Answer (score 1):

Your `test` variable is a list, because `readlines()` returns a list of all lines read.

Since you said the file only contains this one line, you probably wish to perform the replace on only the first line that you read:

```
removestrings = test[0].replace('[', '').replace('[', '').replace('\\', '').replace("'", '').replace('n', '')
```

Comment: Your code succesfully removes the characters but it doesn't work in my command still. I tried to do `subprocess.Popen(['echo', removestrings], universal_newlines=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
                for line in status.stdout:
                    sys.stdout.write(line) ` to see what its output was and i'm getting an exception value saying **[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified**

Comment: This answer is over complexed given the solution is pretty straight forward.

Comment: Well it sounds to me as if... the system can't find your file :|
Any other information you might provide on the matter?

Comment: @SufiyanGhori It's literally just his own code with three characters ([, 0 and ]) added.

Comment: agree, but you can tell OP that all the work he is doing can be simplified. OP probably didn't know `readlines()` returns a list object.

Comment: @SufiyanGhori Well yes, good point. I tend to prefer explaining the issue at hand first and foremost though, and not rewrite OP's entire code. That way it might be easier for them to understand what the problem was in the first place and not just think that their code is bad. Agreed, though, that it's also good to see some better approaches, and some of the other answers here do a better job at that.

Comment: @Berthur as written in Sufiyan's answer below 

The file is in the same directory as my terminal is in, and if I use print(line) just before i call my subprocess command there's no issue grabbing the string and outputting it. But once its assigned into my subprocess commmand, the system seems to screw up somehow.

Comment: @SufiyanGhori You're right that I didnt know that. Just a newbie trying to learn and I appreciate everyones answer and effort to help me :)

Answer (score 1):

You can read the whole file and split lines using str.splitlines:

```
test = t.read().splitlines()
```

Answer (score 1):

### Where you went wrong...

`file.readlines()` in python returns an array (collection or grouping of the same variable type) of the lines in the file -- arrays in python are called lists. you, here are treating the list as a string. you must first target the string inside it, then apply that string-only function.

In this case however, this would not work as you are trying to change the way the python interpretter has displayed it for one to understand.

#### Further information...

In code it would not be a string - we just can't easily understand the stack, heap and memory addresses easily. The example below would work for *any* number of lines (but it will only print the first element) you will need to change that and

#### *this* may be useful...

you could perhaps make the variables globally available (so that other parts of the program can read them

#### more useless stuff

before they go out of scope - the word used to mean the points at which the interpreter (what runs the program) believes the variable is useful - so that it can remove it from memory, or in much larger programs only worry about the locality of variables e.g. when using for loops i is used a lot without scope there would need to be a different name for each variable in the whole project. scopes however get specialised (meaning that if a scope contains the re-declaration of a variable this would fail as it is already seen as being one. an easy way to understand this might be to think of them being branches and the connections between the tips of branches. they don't touch along with their variables.

## solution?

### e.g:

```
with open(logfilenavn, 'r') as file:
  lines = file.readlines() # creates a list
  # an in-line for loop that goes through each item and takes off the last character: \n - the newline character
  #this will work with any number of lines
  strippedLines = [line[:-1] for line in lines]
  #or
  strippedLines = [line.replace('\n', '') for line in lines]
  #you can now print the string stored within the list
  print(strippedLines[0]) # this prints the first element in the list
```

I hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

`readlines` will return a list of lines, and you can't use `replace` with a list.

If you really want to use `readlines`, you should know that it doesn't remove the newline character from the end, you'll have to do it yourself.

```
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in t.readlines()]
```

But still, after removing the newline character yourself from the end of each line, you'll have a list of lines. And from the question, it looks like, you only have one line, you can just access first line `lines[0]`.

Or you can just leave out `readlines`, and just use `read`, it'll read all of the contents from the file. And then just do `rstrip`.

```
contents = t.read().rstrip('\n')
```